# How to get vim syntax highlighting to work along with concealing?

Tags: haskell, vim

I'm using [HaskellConcealPlus](https://github.com/enomsg/vim-haskellConcealPlus) to conceal certain elements of Haskell code, and haskell.vim from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3034) to get better syntax highlighting for Haskell. Below is what it looks like :

[image]

The problem is that the `div`, after being concealed, loses it's orange highlighting, which leads to inconsistency when '/' is highlighted orange, but '÷' is white, even though they're both infix operators. Is there a way to get the syntax highlighting and concealing to both work?

Answer (score 4):

As soon as parts of text get concealed they get colorized as defined by the highlighting group `Conceal`. `:help hl-Conceal` will tell you more details about the group. `:highlight` will show you all highlight groups and their color declarations. E.g. my conceal group looks like as shown below:

```
Conceal        xxx ctermfg=4 ctermbg=0 guifg=#8fa1b3 guibg=#2b303b
```

In order to get more decent colors you can of course set a custom color and properties for your conceal group inside your `.vimrc`. Below is an example which will use bold, underlined text, uses ANSI color 9 as the foreground color and ANSI color 0 as a background color for all files with an `hs` extension:

```
augroup AdjustConceal
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme *.hs highlight Conceal cterm=bold,underline ctermfg=9 ctermbg=0
augroup END
```

Alternatively you could simply link to an existing highlighting group. The example below would link from `Conceal` to `Search`:

```
augroup AdjustConceal
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme *.hs highlight link Conceal Search
augroup END
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably just do this, so I'm SOL if I want different highlights for the concealed words, based on how they would have been highlighted without the concealing?

Comment: Just tried the first suggestion, but the colors didn't change, still looks like it did in the image I posted, any ideas why?

Comment: Do you use Vim on the terminal or some gui flavor like gVim or MacVim?

Comment: The `autocmds` I provided should apply to files with a `.hs` file extension. So I don't know if your files have that extension. But you could try to use a wildcard `*` as a test.

Comment: @MarcusBuffett Were you able to get different highlighting for different categories of code? I'm trying to conceal the comment marker `NB.` in `J`, but it breaks the comment highlighting.